# How to catch errors in XQuery 3.0?

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0

I am reading the [W3C Recommendation for XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xquery-30-20140408/#id-try-catch). Here is what I tried to do:

```
try {
   3 div 0
} catch err:XPTY0004{
   'typing error'
} catch * {
   $err:code || '&#10;' ||
   $err:description || '&#10;' ||
   $err:value || '&#10;' ||
   $err:module || '&#10;' ||
   $err:line-number || '&#10;' ||
   $err:additional
}
```

When trying to save the file, Altova XMLSpy gave me an error: Undefined namespace prefix 'err'.

How should I go about defining err first to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `err` prefix is not bound to any namespace, so you need to explicitly declare it in the query dialog:

```
declare namespace err = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors";
try { 3 div 0 } catch err:FOAR0001 { 'gotcha' }
```

In some query processors, this prefix is predeclared.